# Changing input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I got a situation in which, I am validating input type using jquery.
I have html drop down list which contains different parameters(`"select:first-child"`).
I am trying validating input box based on these parameters for this I have written following code in jquery.
For example-
If I select "Quantity" then input box should take only numbers.
If I select "TradeDate" then input box should take date.

Now problem is ,when I select parameter which has type date , datepicker appears to select date.
But when I select any other parameter having type numbers ,input still showing datepicker.

So, Where I am wrong ,I want each time this validation

Here var type[1] contains type of parameter eg. float,date,char etc.

```
 $("#cond_div").children("select:first-child").change(function(event){
            var temp = $(this).val();
            var type = temp.split("_");

            $("#cond_div").children("input").on("keypress keyup", function () {

                if (type[1].localeCompare("date") == 0) {
                    $(this).datepicker();
                } 
                else if (type[1].localeCompare("float") == 0) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
                    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                } 
                else if (type[1].localeCompare("int") == 0) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
                    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED...
Instead of going with tricky logic ,found a simple way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cond_div").children("select:first-child").change(function (event) {
        var temp = $(this).val();
        var type = temp.split("_");
        console.log("->" + temp);
        console.log("->" + type);

        $("#cond_div").children("input").val("");
        $("#cond_div").children("input").datepicker("destroy");


        if (type[1].localeCompare("date") === 0) {
            console.log(type[1]);
            $("#cond_div").children("input").datepicker();
        } else if (type[1].localeCompare("char") === 0) {
            console.log(type[1]);
            $("#cond_div").children("input").attr("type", "text");
        } else if (type[1].localeCompare("float") === 0) {
            console.log(type[1]);
            $("#cond_div").children("input").attr("type", "number");

        } else if (type[1].localeCompare("int") === 0) {
            console.log(type[1]);
            $("#cond_div").children("input").attr("type", "number");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've transformed an input with the .datepicker() creator, it stays that way until you destroy it by calling .datepicker("destroy") function.

Comment: Hi @ChrisBE ,added .datepicker("destroy") before keypress event occurs ...but still when I select numeric parameter and then parameter with string value selected..it doesn't allow me to input chars or vice versa

Comment: Actually, you destroy the datepicker when the select changes to anything else than a date

Comment: yes ,But how can I do that with other data type logic? @ChrisBE

Comment: Ideally, you may want to separate the select.change and the input.on(keypress keyup) functions.
When select changes, adapt your input accordingly (activate or destroy datepicker).
On keypress on your input, do your input validation according to the select value.